# Absolute exact LIKE string condition in db_select

Tags: database

My query:

```
  $query = db_select('file_managed', 'f');
  $query->join('field_data_field_drupalcon', 'v', 'v.entity_id = f.fid');
  $output = $query
    ->fields('f', array('fid'))
    ->condition('v.bundle', 'video', '=')
    ->condition('v.field_drupalcon_value', '%'.db_like($keywords).'%')
    ->orderRandom()
    ->execute();
```

In the condition I would like to return an absolute exact match to the keyword, so for example if my field value is 'DrupalConDublin' I would not see that where my keyword value is just 'DrupalCon'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get exact matches, you might want to use another operator instead of "LIKE".

For a single value, you might use the following (with the '=' operator):

```
->condition('v.field_drupalcon_value', $keyword, '=')
```

For several keyword values, you might use the 'IN' operator:

```
->condition('v.field_drupalcon_value', $keywords, 'IN')
```

(in that case, `$keywords` must be an array of values).

You can find more information about conditional clauses in the DB API documentation: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/conditional-clauses